# Images have absolute path - How to use a subdirectory URL in LaravelMix

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

My Laravel Mix app will be placed in a subdirectory on the server like: *http://localhost/pat-os-server/public/*

An image's path in my vue component compiles from

```
<img id="logo" src="../assets/img/pat_logo.png">
```

To

```
<img id="logo" src="/images/pat_logo.png">
```

Now the image is not shown due to the subdirectory the app is in. The correct path should be either ***images/pat_logo.png*** (relative - prefered) or ***/pat-os-server/public/images/pat_logo.png*** (absolute)

I've tried to set the output path in webpack.mix.js like this:

```
mix.setPublicPath('/pat-os-server/public/');
mix.setResourceRoot('/pat-os-server/public/');
```

But that doesn't change the output path. It's still ***/images/pat_logo.png***. I expect it to be ***/pat-os-server/public/images/pat_logo.png*** now. Using other values for setPublicPath and setResourceRoot including "/" and "" doesn't caused any difference.

I've placed the path setting methods before calling other methods, so my current webpack.mix.js looks like this:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('/pat-os-server/public/');
mix.setResourceRoot('/pat-os-server/public/');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

How do I get a relative output path for my images or change the absolute path?

Thanks for your support.

**Edit**

I've just realized, that a subfolder "pat-os-server" was created inside my laravel project and all compiled project files where copied into this subfolder. So it seems I missunderstood the setPublicPath setting.

I *don't* want to place the output files into another folder. I want the URLs in my project to point to the correct path which is not the host/root but a subdirectory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answering my own question after a couple of hours of search and trial.

Now my webpack.mix.js looks like this:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
mix
  .setResourceRoot("")
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

This will lead to beautifull relative URLs:

```
<img id="logo" src="images/pat_logo.png">
```

**More Examples**

Use `mix.setResourceRoot("/")` to get an absolute path to the root (should be default):

```
<img id="logo" src="/images/pat_logo.png">
```

Or use anything else like `mix.setResourceRoot("anything/there/")`:

```
<img id="logo" src="anything/there/images/pat_logo.png">
```

Cheers