# Laravel Mix - URL Processing works wrong when web site on localhost is not in root folder

Tags: css, laravel, sass, laravel-mix

Web server structure:

```
localhost/my_site_folder/public
```

When I am using url(../images/example.png) in my scss file, mix automatically finds example.png, copy it to my public/images folder, and then rewrites the url() within my generated stylesheet (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#url-processing)

Cool feature and everything seems fine, except fact, that link was generated as it was described in docs `background: url(/images/example.png?d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e);`, but in my case this link is to `localhost/images/example.png?d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` but I need to `localhost/my_site_folder/public/images/example.png?d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`.

And I can't find where I could setup my website root folder path.

P.S. for example, in laravel it could be done via .env file APP_URL=http://localhost/my_site_folder/public

Is there is something similar in mix?

Comment: I will write here my idea of WorkAround, I would copy everything from resources/assets/images to public/images by myself (.copy() method) and then use option for mix: processCssUrls: false. Then I will be able to use relative path like a ../images/example.png. But if it's normal to do like this, I don't know

Comment: Are you aware that a leading slash in an url means _from the root of the server_, while no leading slash means _from the current directory_? In other words, removing the leading slash in your scss file should fix the issue.

Comment: @Namoshek, Thanks for answer. But please, read carefully https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#url-processing. I am using without leading slash: "url(../images/example.png) in my scss file". Mix automatically adds leading slash.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have misread your question like three times or so. Please have a look at this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797603/images-have-absolute-path-how-to-use-a-subdirectory-url-in-laravelmix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This do the trick `mix.setResourceRoot("../")`.
Thanks to Namoshek comment.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
php artisan storage:link
```

will be the answer?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem